# How to highlight printf, scanf in Vim?

Tags: c, vim, macvim, c11

I've installed macvim with Homebrew;
OS X version 10.11.6; macvim version:

```
macvim: stable 8.0-119 (bottled), HEAD
```

But it doesn't color `printf`, `scanf` by default while editing "my file.c".

I've searched that how to add them by creating `~/.vim/after/c.vim`.
(another way come through my mind is to edit the default c.vim file directly, but I don't know where they are).

In my `~/.vim/after/c.vim` I wrote:

```
syn keyword printf scarf
```

and it didn't work...(If I know where the default c.vim file is, I could refer to it and maybe my problem could be solved.)

btw, I download [c.vim from vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3064),
but I found the last-edited date was in 2010, if I want the C11 standard version where could I get one, if it matters(?).

Is it a good practice that not to change the default syntax-highlight-file like c.vim, and add my own by `~/.vim/after/` or `~/.vim/syntax/`?

Comment: Default files will be under `$VIMRUNTIME`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` file (as recommended in the [official documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#mysyntaxfile-add)) with the following content:

```
syn keyword cFunctions printf scanf
hi link cFunctions Function
```

As far as I can see, the default syntax rules do not highlight the functions, even from the standard library. So you need to add them yourself.

---

The `syn` command adds `printf` and `scanf` to the `cFunctions` highlighting group.

The `hi` command links `cFunctions` group to the `Function` highlight group, which is usually defined by the colorscheme. If the `Function` group is not defined, you can define it yourself, e.g.

```
hi Function term=underline cterm=bold ctermfg=LightGray
```

---

> Is it a good practice that not to change the default syntax-highlight-file like c.vim, and add my own by `~/.vim/after/` or `~/.vim/syntax/`?

Yes, of course. The syntax files are usually distributed as packages. For example, on my Gentoo Linux `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/c.vim` is shipped with `app-editors/vim-core` package. The local modifications to the syntax files will be overwritten the next time the package is upgraded.

Comment: May I ask the difference between the ~/.vim/syntax/c.vim and ~/.vim/after/c.vim? if this question is trivial just ignore it.

Comment: @N1ng, it's interesting question actually. The  [after directory](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#after-directory) is used for different overrules including syntax rules. I can't find why, but `~/.vim/after/c.vim` seems to be processed before syntax highlighting is applied.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more than one library, while programing C, for example GTK2, GTK3, glib, gimp, etc;  you cand add all of them in the same directory  `/home/juan/.vim/after/syntax/c/`.

Otherwise you just need the `/home/juan/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`